# binding Model to MVC Telerik Grid throws error (ControllerContext Null Exception)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

On my view i have multiple telerik MVC grid rendering.
But i only have problem with one.

there is no difference in how the Model is binding to the partialview.

does this exception gives any clue how to fix it.

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: controllerContext 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: controllerContext

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: controllerContext]
   System.Web.Mvc.ChildActionValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +547459
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory) +34
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +151
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +87
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +327
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +281
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +40

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +0
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +72
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +335
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +28
   System.Web.SecurityUtils.MethodInfoInvoke(MethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] args) +159
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +482
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +1424
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +194
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +126
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +1380
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +194
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeDictionary(IDictionary o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +527
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +1319
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +194
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +26
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +74
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj) +6
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +216
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8969117
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

## updated

---

**Controller:**

```
  [GridAction]
            public ActionResult CopaySummaryLevel(int PBMID)
            {
                CopayModel cModel = new CopayModel();
                List<CopayModel> _CopayModel = cModel.GetSummaryLevelCopay(PBMID);
                return PartialView("_CopayGridSummaryLevel", new GridModel<CopayModel>
                {
                    Data = _CopayModel
                });
            }
```

**View:**

```
  @model IEnumerable<HRORx.Models.BenefitsFormularyModel>
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
<h4>
    Summary Level Copay</h4>
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<HRORx.Models.CopayModel>()
            .Name("CopaySummaryLevel")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            //columns.Bound(e => e.PharmacyType).Title("Pharmacy Type");
            columns.Bound(e => e.OutOfPocketRangeStart);//.Title("OP Start");
            //columns.Bound(e => e.OutOfPocketRangeEnd).Title("OP End");
            //columns.Bound(e => e.FlatCopayAmount).Title("Flat Fee");
            //columns.Bound(e => e.PercentCopayRate).Title("% Copay");
            //columns.Bound(e => e.MinimumCopay).Title("Min. Copay");
            columns.Bound(e => e.MaximumCopay);//.Title("Max. Copay");//.Format("{0:c}")
        })
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("Record_onRowDataBound"))
        .ClientEvents(ev => ev.OnComplete("ShowOrHide"))
                                .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("CopaySummaryLevel", "BenefitsFormulary", new { PBMID = Model.FirstOrDefault().HealthPlanMappingID }))
        .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(3))
        .NoRecordsTemplate("No Summary Level Copy Information is available for this Medication.")
        .Sortable()
)
```

**Script:**

```
function Record_onRowDataBound(e) {
    var grid = $(this).data('tGrid');
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your View and the Controller action that renders it?

Comment: @CDSmith i have updated my question with code for controller and view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I got this fixed.
Hope my answer may be useful to any of you with similar issue.

## solution:

Avoid inheriting Controller class in to the Model

```
public class MyModel:Controller
{
}
```

<del>:Controller</del>